# Is this a good plan to build muscle?

Tags: workout-routines

I am using Fitness AI ap that regulates variety, sets, reps, weight.

It seems to always give (2 chest, 2 back, 1 shoulder) compound exercises for upper, and (3 leg, 2 ab) exercises for lower. They are always 4-5 sets, 8-12 reps. I chose 'upper, lower' routine (u, l, rest, u, l, rest, rest)

Is this workout intense enough to build muscle? Like, I know just doing 2 exercises for upper body two times a week isn't enough, but I'm not sure about 5 exercises with this set and rep.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Is this workout intense enough to build muscle?

We can't possibly answer that, as the extent to which a workout program is adequate to drive muscle growth will depend on how difficult the exercises are, which depends on how much resistance they provide relative to your own strength level, and we can't tell that just from the weights and reps provided.

75lbs on the bench press for 4 sets of 9 reps definitely is enough to build muscle when performed by someone who could only manage at most 10 reps with 75lbs. But it would do nothing for someone who could bench 225lbs for 10 reps. It would also stop being effective as the trainee in the former case got stronger.

> Like, I know just doing 2 exercises for upper body two times a week isn't enough

That is not correct. Plenty of people have gotten very strong with just bench press and overhead press as their only upper body lifts. You really can get away with minimal variety when you're doing compound lifts.

Comment: Omg reslly? Thank you! ‍♂️

Comment: Kind of but i did this exercise for a week and it seems to target my lower body more, so my upper body doesnt feel like it worked out enough even when i lifted as much as possible :(