# Is this workout routine good?

Tags: workout-routines, workout

2 times a week (6 days), increase weight, set, rep over time

I'm a beginner (about 1 month now). The weight in the pictures aren't accurate though

I am mostly worried about growing a balanced body, and other things (like other people, even a beginner, seem to workout so intense compared to this routine, etc)

The app changes exercises every time, but it always recommend 3 chest exercise, 2 tricep, 3 back, 2 bicep, 3 leg, 2 shoulder

Goal is mainly hypertrophy not strength

I researched a lot online and made this routine, but wanted advice from experienced people

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this a good plan to build muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/46437/is-this-a-good-plan-to-build-muscle)

Comment: I'd move the overhead press from day 3 to day 1 and get rid of tricep extension. I'd put RDLs into your leg day to get some hamstrings. The weight seems low on your squat compared to your upper body lifts.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber - That sounds like the beginning of a good answer, maybe you could add some details about why and make that an answer? We try to avoid having answers in comments as they can disappear at any time.